# Custom Spinner always shows selected item, even when none is selected

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

Odd behaviour from my spinner. I have custom spinner that should show a string "Select Item:" when nothing has been selected. When something has been selected it should update with the selected item. I ran a `setOnItemSelectedListener` but it always a selected item. Basically the first in the list. Here is my `getView()` code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_placeholder, parent, false);

        itemText = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.itemText);
        final String userSelection = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                itemText.setText(userSelection);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                itemText.setText("Select item below");
            }
        });
        return row;
    }
```

Does anyone know why this happens? I assume I have set it up correctly. I moved the `setOnItemSelectedListener` to the `oncreate()` outside of my custom adapter but it still showed the same results. When you load the page with the spinner, it shows the first item always, even before the user has selected anything.

Any help is appreciate, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as a Spinner's adapter contains at least one item, one of those items will always be selected. By default that will be position zero, i.e. the first in the list as you are seeing here. With a Spinner, there really isn't a concept of no item being selected.

Also, onNothingSelected() doesn't do what you think it does. From the documentation:

"Callback method to be invoked when the selection disappears from this view. The selection can disappear for instance when touch is activated or when the adapter becomes empty."

The simple solution to your issue is to have the first item in your adapter's list set to 'Select item below'. Then elsewhere in your code, if getSelectedItemPosition() returns zero, you know that no valid selection has yet been made.

EDIT:

If using a cursor adapter, you can get a 'Please select' row as the first entry using a UNION. For example:

```
SELECT _id, item, 1 AS sort
FROM table
UNION
SELECT 0 AS _id, 'Please select' AS item, 0 AS sort
ORDER BY sort, date
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Hmmm. I might just have it show the first one then. I'm pulling the spinner items from a database and it's based on time so it would be too much hassle to set up for such a simple thing. Little disappointing that it can't be set up this way but oh well.

Comment: If it's a cursor adapter, you can try to get the 'Select item' row in the cursor using a UNION and ORDERing it to the top. But as you say, it depends if it's worth the hassle. Please see my edit above for an example of what I mean.

Comment: Thanks. I know which direction to look into now if I decide to go ahead with it.